# How pass TEXT data type to stored procedure in hana

Tags: stored-procedures, hana

I'm writing a simple stored procedure for my Hana database, its behavior is to update a table and return the updated element. Here the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "UpdateTbl" (in _id integer, in formula text) AS

BEGIN

    UPDATE "MyTable" SET "formula" = formula, WHERE "id" = _id;

    SELECT "id", "formula" FROM "MyTable" WHERE "id" = _id;

END;
```

The problem i'm facing is that I cannot specify a TEXT input parameter in stored procedures.
A possible workaround could be to use NVARCHAR instead.
In this way, I can correctly create the stored procedure, but when I run it with 'dummy' value in the NVARCHAR field, i got this error

*Error: (dberror) [7]: feature not supported: "Database"."UpdateTbl": ... : Unregistered function name: "to_text*

It seems that it cannot convert NVARCHAR in TEXT.
So, there is a way to force the conversion of this kind of parameter in TEXT?
If not, there is a way I'm not considering to pass TEXT parameter as input (other data types, for instance)?

Thnaks in advance

Answer (score 0):

this simple example works as expected when using `NVARCHAR` or `NCLOB` as procedure parameter type

```
DROP TABLE t1;
CREATE TABLE t1 (i int, t text fast preprocess off);

INSERT INTO t1 values(3,'');
INSERT INTO t1 values(4,'');

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p1 (in i int, in t nclob) AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE t1 SET t = :t WHERE i = :i;
    --SELECT i,t FROM t1 where i = :i;
END;

CALL p1(3,'bob went to london');
CALL p1(4,'nancy moved to berlin');

SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE CONTAINS(*,'go',linguistic);
```

please provide your column properties

Comment: There is an important limitation to this approach: the `TEXT` datatype in SAP HANA yields an `NCLOB` column. While you can, of course, set the value of the `TEXT` column to the value of an `NVARCHAR` column, you limit the contents of the `TEXT` column to that of the `NVARCHAR`.

Comment: My choice is to use input parameter of NVARCHAR type. I agree with the limitation described by @LarsBr. but I don't have any better solution at the moment